# What are the resources for list of error messages in case of failed transaction on eCommerce website?

Tags: error-message

Being the only UX guy in my company, my management wants me to write error messages for their customers. Dev team is really very very bad when it comes to writing and they will just say UserNameInvalid and PasswordNotValid and stuff like that.

Now i have taken up this assignment of repairing all the string messages and make them user friendly. Basic error messages i could write but when it comes to the payment gateway error messages, i am stuck. Most of them are like UnexpectedTransactionDetailsError or PaymentGatewayResponseEmpty.

Can anybody help please?

Comment: If you look at the right sidebar, there's a section called "Related", which contains multiple similar questions with excellent answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually every Payment Gateways have developer documentations. In those documentations, they have list of all transaction status codes & their respective message.

So based on the error status code, you can have your own mapping of error messages to be displayed. How to have the error mapping is a question for stackoverflow

I am aware of PayTm & Paypal having this list of transaction status codes & failure messages in their documentation.

For Paypal - https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/errorcodes

Comment: Welcome. Wait for sometime & see if others have a better response to your question. If not, and if my answer satisfies you then do consider accepting it :)